# HTML Input goes big when starting typing, because height is set to 100%

Tags: html, css

Edit: It appears this issue was caused by not having `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of my code, but adding this now breaks the whole layout: https://jsfiddle.net/7vpn20oh/1/

On my website I created a little text input field using `<input type="text" id="inputMessage">` inside of a form. I then used CSS and did the following:

```css
#inputMessage {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: 100%;
}
```

which kind of works. I can even click the text box and it still works fine. But at the moment where I start typing, the text box just goes huge.
Here is a Gif of it: https://i.gyazo.com/cb8752209d92b75260a1f149c5721fbb.gif

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is most likely caused by other stuff, e.g. the input-parent height, the line-height or JS. Show us your full HTML and CSS (and JS if you use it) or recreate the error in a JSFiddle. Without this, it's hard/impossible for us to tell what's wrong.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed the provided jsfiddle by changing `height: 100%` inside the body selector to `height: 100vh` and now everything's working as expected (the layout is not broken, the input does not grow).

I maintain that `height: 100%` to the #inputMessage element is at best useless and at worst harmful. When I removed it in my codepen it makes no difference.

See working code here : https://codepen.io/marc-simplon/pen/BgagMY

(I also made small changes to the width of #inputMessage and #inputButton )

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: So, I tried to upload the code to JSFiddle, and I noticed something interested. It works on there. And I already have a guess on why. As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/7vpn20oh/1/ it works on JSFiddle, but the layout just looks really wierd (it should all go over the whole page). And I get this exact same aswell, when I add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of my page, but now the problem is that, like I said, the whole layout is broken...

Comment: `<script defer src="http://localhost:6554/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` line 9 of the html could not obviously be loaded (likely creating layout issues ?). You should include relevant js code in your jsfiddle

Comment: I just tried to remove that locally, it has nothing to do with it. I just think that JSFiddle automatically adds <!DOCTYPE html> internally. But I have no Idea, on why DOCTYPE html breaks my layout

Comment: The layout in your jsfiddle doesn't take all the space because of the `height: 100%;` in your body selector. 100% means 100% of the *parent* element. If there is not parent or the parent as no defined height then no size get defined. Replace `height: 100%` with `height: 100vh` then your layout works as expected.